# How calculates curves in GIMP?

Tags: curve, gimp

I have file of `gimp curves` in old style, like this:

```
# GIMP Curves File
0 0 45 79 166 134 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 255 255 
0 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 255 255 
0 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 255 255 
0 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 255 255 
0 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 255 255
```

Every pair is point with x,y koordinates (except -1,-1). I need calculate y-val for the curve by x in range(0, 255). Which algorithm I need use?

Comment: it might help if you can point to something that explains the format of this file and its curve definitions, for people who know a lot about curves, but know nothing about this particular file format.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans first string - brigtness, other: rgba channels. Every pair of numbers is x and y coordinates. -1 means incalid value. First pair in line is begin of curve, last - end of curve

Comment: Look like "very old" style ("old" being Gimp 2.8). Are you targeting Gimp 2.8 or Gimp 2.10?

Comment: That's not really a good enough explanation, do you have a link to the format's specification? (I assume it's in the gimp documentation for the version this came from, which version is that and what's the documentation link?)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans unfortunately I did not found any specification

Comment: @xenoid I use gimp 2.10